# Django generates form's dropdown very oddly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have this dropdown with choices which its choices are based on an Enum and form is generated on admin , however 2 of the choices have a weird value and are wrapped by parentheses, I have been using dropdowns like this and it's first time this happening, any idea why this is happening? thanks

my enum:

```
class ProjectPublicState(object):
    OPEN_FOR_APPLICATIONS = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2
    CLOSED = 3,
    NOT_PUBLIC = 4,

    @classmethod
    def default(cls):
        return cls.OPEN_FOR_APPLICATIONS
```

in my model:

```
PUBLIC_STATE_CHOICES = (
        (ProjectPublicState.OPEN_FOR_APPLICATIONS, _('Open for Applications')),
        (ProjectPublicState.IN_PROGRESS, _('In Progress')),
        (ProjectPublicState.CLOSED, _('Closed')),
        (ProjectPublicState.NOT_PUBLIC, _('Not Public')),
    )
```

and (changing it to models.IntegerField didn't fix it either)

```
 state_public = FSMIntegerField(
        _('Public State'),
        choices=PUBLIC_STATE_CHOICES,
        default=ProjectPublicState.default()
    )
```

and the result:

```
<select name="state_public" id="id_state_public" class="form-control">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Open for Applications</option>
<option value="2">In Progress</option>
<option value="(3,)">Closed</option>
<option value="(4,)">Not Public</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is because you have accidentally converted variables `CLOSED` and `NOT_PUBLIC` to [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) by putting a comma at the end.**

As per Python docs on [tuples:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

> A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas.

You should **remove the trailing comma at the end** and it should work fine.

```
class ProjectPublicState(object):
    OPEN_FOR_APPLICATIONS = 1
    IN_PROGRESS = 2
    CLOSED = 3 # remove the trailing comma
    NOT_PUBLIC = 4 # remove the trailing comma

    @classmethod
    def default(cls):
        return cls.OPEN_FOR_APPLICATIONS
```

**For example:**

```
In [1]: foo = 1, # assign 'foo' as 1 with a trailing comma at the end

In [2]: foo # print foo
Out[2]: (1,) # a tuple and not just a number 

In [3]: foo = 1,2,3 # Now assign multiple values separated by commas

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: (1, 2, 3) # tuple of 3 elements
```